# Move/Adjust line on canvas up and down in 2D view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas

I'm working on an Android app for a backup camera simulation that requires to draw a virtual parking Grid lines (Red, Yellow & Green).

**Requirements:**

- user to be able to move/adjust parking lines left and right
  (done!!).
- user to be able to move every side of the grid line up and down (in
  2D if I'm correct) in a way like this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXsYozXpy8g) (*Which I'm
  trying to figure out*)

what I'm thinking is that X should be fixed and Y changes according to user input whether it's on touch or button click.
I'm new to android, i hope someone could direct me to the right path.
**The method to draw the grid lines on the canvas:**

```
private void drawHorizontalLines(Canvas canvas){
    Paint paintGreen = new Paint();
    //Log.d(TAG, "Width = " + canvas.getClipBounds().width() + " Height = " + canvas.getClipBounds().height());
    //if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    if(inCalibrationMode == false)
        getGridLines(canvas);
    {
        paintGreen.setStrokeWidth(10);
        //Log.d(TAG, ""+ Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)));
        //left side
        paintGreen.setColor(Color.RED );
        int topPoint = dangerousLineY;//height - (gridTopPoint*3)/10;
        int bottomPoint = gridBottomPoint;
        int letfPoint = gridLeftPoint;
        canvas.drawLine(letfPoint, bottomPoint, letfPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE))), topPoint, paintGreen);


        letfPoint = dangerousLineXLeft; //letfPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)));
        bottomPoint = topPoint;
        canvas.drawLine(letfPoint, bottomPoint, letfPoint + 100, bottomPoint, paintGreen);


        //letfPoint = letfPoint + 10;
        bottomPoint -= 30;
        letfPoint = letfPoint + (int) (30 * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)));
        topPoint = warningLineY;
        paintGreen.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawLine(letfPoint, bottomPoint, letfPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5))), topPoint, paintGreen);

        letfPoint = letfPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5)));
        bottomPoint = topPoint;
        canvas.drawLine(letfPoint, bottomPoint, letfPoint + 100, bottomPoint, paintGreen);

        bottomPoint -= 30;
        letfPoint = letfPoint + (int) (30 * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5)));
        topPoint = safeLineY;
        paintGreen.setColor(Color.GREEN );
        canvas.drawLine(letfPoint, bottomPoint, letfPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 10))), topPoint, paintGreen);

        letfPoint = letfPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 10)));
        bottomPoint = topPoint;
        canvas.drawLine(letfPoint, bottomPoint, letfPoint + 100, bottomPoint, paintGreen);

        //right side
        paintGreen.setColor(Color.RED );
        topPoint = dangerousLineY;
        bottomPoint = gridBottomPoint;
        int rightPoint = gridRightPoint;
        canvas.drawLine(rightPoint, bottomPoint, rightPoint - (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE))), topPoint, paintGreen);

        rightPoint = dangerousLineXRight;
        bottomPoint = topPoint;
        canvas.drawLine(rightPoint, bottomPoint, rightPoint - 100, bottomPoint, paintGreen);


        bottomPoint -= 30;
        rightPoint = rightPoint - (int) (30 * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)));
        topPoint = warningLineY;
        paintGreen.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawLine(rightPoint, bottomPoint, rightPoint - (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5))), topPoint, paintGreen);

        rightPoint = rightPoint - (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5)));
        bottomPoint = topPoint;
        canvas.drawLine(rightPoint, bottomPoint, rightPoint - 100, bottomPoint, paintGreen);

        bottomPoint -= 30;
        rightPoint = rightPoint - (int) (30 * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5)));
        topPoint = safeLineY;
        paintGreen.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawLine(rightPoint, bottomPoint, rightPoint - (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 10))), topPoint, paintGreen);

        rightPoint = rightPoint - (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 10)));
        bottomPoint = topPoint;
        canvas.drawLine(rightPoint, bottomPoint, rightPoint - 100, bottomPoint, paintGreen);


            setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, blue);
        }
    }
}
```

**onTouchEvent to move the grid left and right**

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (isInCalibrationMode()) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        Log.d(TAG, "-------------------------" + eventX + ":" + eventY);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //first check if we fall into the range of distance line
                Log.d(TAG, "" + eventX + ":" + eventY);
                if (inCalibrationMode == true) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "*" + safeLineXLeft + ":" + safeLineXRight + ":" + safeLineY);
                        if (
                            Math.abs(eventX - gridLeftPoint) <= DISTANCE_MOVE_RANGE && Math.abs(eventY - gridBottomPoint) <= DISTANCE_MOVE_RANGE
                            ) {
                        //move left side
                        moveGrid = MOVE_GRID_LEFT;
                    } else if (
                            Math.abs(eventX - gridRightPoint) <= DISTANCE_MOVE_RANGE && Math.abs(eventY - gridBottomPoint) <= DISTANCE_MOVE_RANGE) {
                        //move right side
                        moveGrid = MOVE_GRID_RIGHT;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.d(TAG, "TOUCH MOVE");
                if (moveGrid == MOVE_GRID_LEFT) {
                    gridLeftPoint = (int) eventX;

                } else if (moveGrid == MOVE_GRID_RIGHT) {
                    gridRightPoint = (int) eventX;
                } else if (moveGrid == MOVE_GRID_DANGEROUS) {
                    dangerousLineY = (int) eventY;

                } else if (moveGrid == MOVE_GRID_WARNING) {
                    warningLineY = (int) eventY;

                } else if (moveGrid == MOVE_GRID_SAFE) {
                    safeLineY = (int) eventY;
                }

                updateDistancePoints(); //update distance points when moving 

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Log.d(TAG, "TOUCH UP");
                //path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                //slearScreen = true;

                moveGrid = MOVE_GRID_NONE;
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                break;

            default:
                return false;
        }

        // Schedules a repaint.
        if (inCalibrationMode == true)
            invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**update grid distance points**

```
//update distance points method
private void updateDistancePoints(){
    //gridTopPoint = height/2+10;


    dangerousLineXLeft = gridLeftPoint + (int) ((gridBottomPoint - dangerousLineY) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)));
    dangerousLineXRight = gridRightPoint - (int) ((gridBottomPoint - dangerousLineY) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)));


    warningLineXLeft = gridLeftPoint +
            (int) ((gridBottomPoint - (dangerousLineY - 30)) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)))  +
            (int) (((dangerousLineY - 30) - warningLineY) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE+5)));

    warningLineXRight = gridRightPoint -
            (int) ((gridBottomPoint - (dangerousLineY - 30)) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)))  -
            (int) (((dangerousLineY - 30) - warningLineY) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE+5)))+200; //test Samira


    safeLineXLeft = gridLeftPoint +
            (int) ((gridBottomPoint - (dangerousLineY - 30)) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)))  +
            (int) (((dangerousLineY - 30) - warningLineY) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE+5))) +
            (int) (((warningLineY) - safeLineY) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE+10)));

    safeLineXRight = gridRightPoint -
            (int) ((gridBottomPoint - dangerousLineY - 30) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)))  -
            (int) (((dangerousLineY - 30) - warningLineY) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE+5))) -
            (int) (( warningLineY - safeLineY) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE+10)));

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was be able to rotate line(s) as follow:
**1- Find the center/rotation point of each line(Xm,Ym)**

Xm=(startX + stopX)/2;

Xy=(startY + stopY)/2;

**2- Calculate the new points to draw the line**

```
x=a*cos⁡(θ)-b*sin(θ)-Xm*cos⁡(θ)+Ym*sin⁡(θ)+Xm
y=a*sin⁡(θ)+b*cos(θ)-Xm*sin⁡(θ)-Ym*cos⁡(θ)+Ym
```

(a, b) old points.
**3- Write a function to draw the line using rotation angle and formula mentioned above**

```
private void drawLinesRotate(Canvas canvas) {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    //rotation angle
    SharedPreferences Angleprefs = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("prefAngles", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    double angle = Angleprefs.getFloat("angle", 0);
    double rotateAngle = Math.toRadians(angle); //rotate angle has to be in radians
//rotation point on the left
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("prefRotate", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        float cX_Left = prefs.getFloat("centerPointLeftX", 0);
        float cY_Left = prefs.getFloat("centerPointLeftY", 0);
        //*******left side********* 
        //RED line
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        int topPoint = dangerousLineY;
        int bottomPoint = gridBottomPoint;
        int leftPoint = gridLeftPoint;
    int newX1 = (int) (Math.cos(rotateAngle) * ((float) leftPoint) - Math.sin(rotateAngle) * (float) bottomPoint - cX_Left * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Left * Math.sin(rotateAngle) + cX_Left);
    int newY1 = (int) (Math.sin(rotateAngle) * leftPoint + bottomPoint * Math.cos(rotateAngle) - cX_Left * Math.sin(rotateAngle) - cY_Left * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Left);
    int newX2 = (int) (Math.cos(rotateAngle) * (leftPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)))) - Math.sin(rotateAngle) * topPoint -
            cX_Left * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Left * Math.sin(rotateAngle) + cX_Left);
    int newY2 = (int) (Math.sin(rotateAngle) * (leftPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)))) + Math.cos(rotateAngle) * topPoint -
            cX_Left * Math.sin(rotateAngle) - cY_Left * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Left);
    canvas.drawLine(newX1, newY1, newX2, newY2, paint);

    leftPoint = dangerousLineXLeft;
    bottomPoint = topPoint;
    //horizontal line
    canvas.drawLine(newX2, newY2, newX2 + 100, newY2, paint);
//        //YELLOW line
    bottomPoint -= 30;
    leftPoint = leftPoint + (int) (30 * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)));
    topPoint = warningLineY;
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

    newX1 = (int) (Math.cos(rotateAngle) * ((float) leftPoint) - Math.sin(rotateAngle) * (float) bottomPoint - cX_Left * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Left * Math.sin(rotateAngle) + cX_Left);
    newY1 = (int) (Math.sin(rotateAngle) * leftPoint + bottomPoint * Math.cos(rotateAngle) - cX_Left * Math.sin(rotateAngle) - cY_Left * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Left);
    newX2 = (int) (Math.cos(rotateAngle) * (leftPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5)))) - Math.sin(rotateAngle) * topPoint -
            cX_Left * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Left * Math.sin(rotateAngle) + cX_Left);
    newY2 = (int) (Math.sin(rotateAngle) * (leftPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5)))) + Math.cos(rotateAngle) * topPoint -
            cX_Left * Math.sin(rotateAngle) - cY_Left * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Left);
    canvas.drawLine(newX1, newY1, newX2, newY2, paint);
    leftPoint = leftPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5)));
    bottomPoint = topPoint;
    canvas.drawLine(newX2, newY2, newX2 + 100, newY2, paint);
//        //GREEN line
        bottomPoint -= 30;
        leftPoint = leftPoint + (int) (30 * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5)));
        topPoint = safeLineY;
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    newX1 = (int) (Math.cos(rotateAngle) * ((float) leftPoint) - Math.sin(rotateAngle) * (float) bottomPoint - cX_Left * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Left * Math.sin(rotateAngle) + cX_Left);
    newY1 = (int) (Math.sin(rotateAngle) * leftPoint + bottomPoint * Math.cos(rotateAngle) - cX_Left * Math.sin(rotateAngle) - cY_Left * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Left);
    newX2 = (int) (Math.cos(rotateAngle) * (leftPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 10)))) - Math.sin(rotateAngle) * topPoint -
            cX_Left * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Left * Math.sin(rotateAngle) + cX_Left);
    newY2 = (int) (Math.sin(rotateAngle) * (leftPoint + (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 10)))) + Math.cos(rotateAngle) * topPoint -
            cX_Left * Math.sin(rotateAngle) - cY_Left * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Left);
    canvas.drawLine(newX1, newY1, newX2, newY2, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(newX2, newY2, newX2 + 100, newY2, paint);

    //*******right side*********
    //rotation point on the right
    float cX_Right = prefs.getFloat("centerPointRightX", 0);
    float cY_Right = prefs.getFloat("centerPointRightY", 0);
    angle *= -1; //right side angle should be (-)
    rotateAngle = Math.toRadians(angle);
    //RED line
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    topPoint = dangerousLineY;
    bottomPoint = gridBottomPoint;
    int rightPoint = gridRightPoint;


    newX1 = (int) (Math.cos(rotateAngle) * ((float) rightPoint) - Math.sin(rotateAngle) * (float) bottomPoint - cX_Right * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Right * Math.sin(rotateAngle) + cX_Right);
    newY1 = (int) (Math.sin(rotateAngle) * rightPoint + bottomPoint * Math.cos(rotateAngle) - cX_Right * Math.sin(rotateAngle) - cY_Right * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Right);
    newX2 = (int) (Math.cos(rotateAngle) * (rightPoint - (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)))) - Math.sin(rotateAngle) * topPoint -
            cX_Right * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Right * Math.sin(rotateAngle) + cX_Right);
    newY2 = (int) (Math.sin(rotateAngle) * (rightPoint - (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)))) + Math.cos(rotateAngle) * topPoint -
            cX_Right * Math.sin(rotateAngle) - cY_Right * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Right);
    canvas.drawLine(newX1, newY1, newX2, newY2, paint); //vertical line

    //horizontal line
    rightPoint = dangerousLineXRight;
    bottomPoint = topPoint;
    canvas.drawLine(newX2, newY2, newX2 - 100, newY2, paint);

    //YELLOW line
    bottomPoint -= 30;
    rightPoint = rightPoint - (int) (30 * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE)));
    topPoint = warningLineY;
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    newX1 = (int) (Math.cos(rotateAngle) * ((float) rightPoint) - Math.sin(rotateAngle) * (float) bottomPoint - cX_Right * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Right * Math.sin(rotateAngle) + cX_Right);
    newY1 = (int) (Math.sin(rotateAngle) * rightPoint + bottomPoint * Math.cos(rotateAngle) - cX_Right * Math.sin(rotateAngle) - cY_Right * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Right);
    newX2 = (int) (Math.cos(rotateAngle) * (rightPoint - (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5)))) - Math.sin(rotateAngle) * topPoint -
            cX_Right * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Right * Math.sin(rotateAngle) + cX_Right);
    newY2 = (int) (Math.sin(rotateAngle) * (rightPoint - (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5)))) + Math.cos(rotateAngle) * topPoint -
            cX_Right * Math.sin(rotateAngle) - cY_Right * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Right);
    canvas.drawLine(newX1, newY1, newX2, newY2, paint); //vertical line
    //horizontal line
    rightPoint = rightPoint - (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5)));
    bottomPoint = topPoint;
    canvas.drawLine(newX2, newY2, newX2 - 100, newY2, paint);

    //GREEN line
    bottomPoint -= 30;
    rightPoint = rightPoint - (int) (30 * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 5)));
    topPoint = safeLineY;
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    newX1 = (int) (Math.cos(rotateAngle) * ((float) rightPoint) - Math.sin(rotateAngle) * (float) bottomPoint - cX_Right * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Right * Math.sin(rotateAngle) + cX_Right);
    newY1 = (int) (Math.sin(rotateAngle) * rightPoint + bottomPoint * Math.cos(rotateAngle) - cX_Right * Math.sin(rotateAngle) - cY_Right * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Right);
    newX2 = (int) (Math.cos(rotateAngle) * (rightPoint - (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 10)))) - Math.sin(rotateAngle) * topPoint -
            cX_Right * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Right * Math.sin(rotateAngle) + cX_Right);
    newY2 = (int) (Math.sin(rotateAngle) * (rightPoint - (int) ((bottomPoint - topPoint) * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(DISTANCE_GRID_ANGLE + 10)))) + Math.cos(rotateAngle) * topPoint -
            cX_Right * Math.sin(rotateAngle) - cY_Right * Math.cos(rotateAngle) + cY_Right);
    canvas.drawLine(newX1, newY1, newX2, newY2, paint); //vertical line
    //horizontal line
    canvas.drawLine(newX2, newY2, newX2 - 100, newY2, paint);
}
```

I increase/decrease rotation angle on button click (*have 2 buttons*) and save it in `SharedPreferences`. Also rotation points have to be saved, as i also move the lines left and right. Call this method on `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`. To better visualize the lines I draw, see attached screenshot.

[image]

I'm sure there are better solutions out there, but this works for me.

Hope it helps others.